# How dynamically insert data in respective tables based upon xml in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have this type of input `XML` parameter pass in stored procedure, which is passed from my `.net` application.

Now, I need to insert records in each respective table:

```
<root>
<table1>
<patid>123</patid>
<name>gresh</name>
<fname>kumar</name>
</table1>
<table2>
<patid>123</patid>
<Schoolname>12345</Schoolname>
</table2>
<tablen>
<patid>123</patid>
<nfield>12345</nfield>
</tablen>
<root>
```

Suppose `table1` will insert data in `table1`, `table2` data in `table2`, `tablen` mean number of other tables may be there in `XML`.

So how it would be possible to insert in each respective tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to get the data from the `XML`. Your case is pretty simple (and I am assuming you are inserting data only in one table only once, but you can solve it for multiple insertions in one table easily). So, the following statement gives me:

```
SELECT T.c.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(128)') AS tableName
      ,T1.c1.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(128)') AS columName
      ,T1.c1.value('(./node())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS value
FROM @XML.nodes('/root/*') T(c)
CROSS APPLY T.c.nodes('*') T1(c1)
```

[image]

Then, you need to group the values for `insertion` for each table (I am using a `CLR` concatenate function (you can find it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx), but you can search for `T-SQL` alternative also):

```
;WITH DataSource(tableName, columName, value)AS
(
    SELECT T.c.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(128)')
          ,T1.c1.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(128)')
          ,T1.c1.value('(./node())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM @XML.nodes('/root/*') T(c)
    CROSS APPLY T.c.nodes('*') T1(c1)
)
SELECT tableName
      ,[dbo].[Concatenate] (columName)
      ,[dbo].[Concatenate] (value)
FROM DataSource
GROUP BY tableName
```

[image]

You can prepare the above code for dynamic execution further like this:.

```
;WITH DataSource(tableName, columName, value)AS
(
    SELECT T.c.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(128)')
          ,T1.c1.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(128)')
          ,T1.c1.value('(./node())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM @XML.nodes('/root/*') T(c)
    CROSS APPLY T.c.nodes('*') T1(c1)
)
SELECT 'INSERT INTO ' + tableName  + '(' + [dbo].[Concatenate] (columName) + ') VALUES(' + [dbo].[Concatenate] ('''' + value + '''') + ');' 
FROM DataSource
GROUP BY tableName
```

[image]

Now, you simple need to build a `dynamic T-SQL string` and execute it using `sp_executesql` procedure:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'<root>
<table1>
<patid>123</patid>
<name>gresh</name>
<fname>kumar</fname>
</table1>
<table2>
<patid>123</patid>
<Schoolname>12345</Schoolname>
</table2>
<tablen>
<patid>123</patid>
<nfield>12345</nfield>
</tablen>
</root>';

DECLARE @DynamicSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH DataSource(tableName, columName, value)AS
(
    SELECT T.c.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(128)')
          ,T1.c1.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(128)')
          ,T1.c1.value('(./node())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM @XML.nodes('/root/*') T(c)
    CROSS APPLY T.c.nodes('*') T1(c1)
)
SELECT @DynamicSQLStatement =
(
    SELECT CHAR(10) + 'INSERT INTO ' + tableName  + '(' + [dbo].[Concatenate] (columName) + ') VALUES(' + [dbo].[Concatenate] ('''' + value + '''') + ');' 
    FROM DataSource
    GROUP BY tableName
    FOR XML PATH, TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @DynamicSQLStatement

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQLStatement
```

[image]

Note, that I am assuming that your `XML` structure is valid in the context of the database - the table exists, the column exists, and the values inserted in the columns are correct.

You can add more check if you need.

Comment: thanks gotqn, when I execute above , I am getting this Error

Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Concatenate", or the name is ambiguous.

I have also use conat function , but unable to resolve.

Comment: In order to use the `[dbo].[Concatenate]` function, you need first to read the following article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx - here you can find everything you need (information and source code) to create this function. If you do not want to use `CLR` functions, you can group the results using this answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/273238/1080354

Comment: SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later can use `STRING_AGG(columnName, ', ')` instead of `[dbo].[Concatenate]`